# Cannot read inputs from React Bootstrap Select

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm using React Bosstrap Select and write a code to access option values from the select.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import {Form} from 'react-bootstrap';

class Race extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            race: 0
        };

        this.onSelectRace = this.onSelectRace.bind(this);
    }

    onSelectRace(e) {
        console.log(e);
        console.log(this.inputEl);
        this.setState({
            race: this.inputEl.value
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h5>Race</h5>{this.state.race}
                <Form>
                    <Form.Group controlId="exampleForm.ControlSelect1">
                        <Form.Label>Select Race</Form.Label>
                        <Form.Control as="select"
                                      onChange={this.onSelectRace.bind(this)}
                                      inputRef={el => this.inputEl = el}>
                            <option value={1}>Human</option>
                            <option value={2}>Elfe</option>
                            <option value={3}>Nain</option>
                            <option value={4}>Halfling</option>
                            <option value={5}>Konizan</option>
                            <option value={6}>Neimada</option>
                        </Form.Control>
                    </Form.Group>
                </Form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Race;
```

I'm trying to get the select input and print it using console.log But my code doesn't work and in the console log, it prints as undefined. How can I get this work?

Comment: Print the "e"  in onSelectRace funtion

Comment: what is `this.inputEl` ?

Comment: also please add the full code of component

Comment: @AtinSingh Added

Comment: Is Bosstrap a thing, or did you mean Bootstrap?

Answer (score 0):

The value of those select options are in `e.target.value`.

Here's an example of it working - https://codesandbox.io/s/react-bootstrap-v6wtc

Also. If you want to print Human and other races instead of 1, 2 etc then you have to give that value to your options instead of 1,2.